# Use Activity method in Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new in Fragment and I am trying use Activity method in Fragment class. So please help me how I use Activity method in Fragment. And also how I use `List<NameValuePair>`, `SharedPreferences` in Fragment.

```
public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment  {

        public DashboardFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
```

This is Fragment code and I want to use Activity method in this. So please help I am new in this section. If there is another method, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can get Activity instance with getActivity() method in Fragment:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
```

Then you can call any Activity method with the instance:

```
activity.method();
```

2) About SharedPreferences, you can also get Context instance with getContext() method in Fragment.

```
Context context = getContext();
```

So you can call getSharedPreferences() method with the instance:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode);
```

3) `List<T>` is a pure Java class. So you can use it in Fragment without any limitation.

Answer (score 0):

After the fragment's `onAttach` method is called (see [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)), you can obtain a reference to the activity through fragment's `getActivity()` method. Then you can cast this reference to the type of your activity and call the method:

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).method();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity method needs to be static and public. Then you could do following in your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof MyActivity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        sharedPreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(...);
    }
}
```

Declare `MyActivity activity` in your Fragment.

then you can call `activity.yourMethod()` in another place. Dont forget to check if activity is null.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface implementation for this. Somethings like this:

Activity:

```
MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CallBack {

  @Override
  public void onCallBack() {
    // do something
  }

}
```

And Fragment:

```
MyFragment extends Fragment {

  public interface CallBack {

    void onCallBack();    

  }

  private CallBack callBack;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity context) {
    callBack = (CallBack) activity;
  }

  // when clicking or whatever it takes to call
  callBack.onCallBack();

}
```